# Why docker-compose creates directories/files with user:group 999:999?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume, file-ownership

I used `docker-compose up` with the following `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3.5'
services:
 mysql-server:
  image: mysql:5.7
  environment:
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root_pwd
  volumes:
   - ./var/lib/mysql:/var/lib/mysql:rw
```

The directory `./var/lib/mysql` does not exist initially.

After running `docker-compose up` ..

`ls -al ./var/lib/mysql` command shows all the files with `user:group` `999:999`.

I cannot find user or group called `999` in my system.

**Why** `docker-compose` chooses to **create files** with a **non-existing uid:gid** ?

In my case, I cannot commit the specific directory unless I change ownership. But even when I do, on a next run, `docker-compose up` updates the ownership again to `999:999`.

What is the solution to the above problem? e.g. Is there a way to instruct docker-compose to map files in host machine with a specific uid:gid pair?

Host: ubuntu-18.04
docker-compose: 1.22.0

Comment: Are you building a non-windows container within a windows system?

Comment: @MattB. My host is ubuntu-18.04.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Docker creates and populates the directory with the user that `mysql` image uses. That user, of course, has an `uid` within the container. That `uid` happens to be 999.

The user with that `uid` exists in the container but does not exist in your host.

On the container the folder looks like this:

```
root@f86ffddac96c:/var/lib# ls -l
total 32
...
drwxr-xr-x 5 mysql mysql 4096 Mar 19 13:06 mysql
...
```

and on the host it ends up looking like this.

```
root@machine:/home/username/mysql/var/lib# ls -l
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 5 999 docker 4096 Mar 19 15:06 mysql
```

This just simply means that the user `mysql` has `uid` of 999. And as you are creating a bind volume from container to host, all files within that volume must have same permissions for same `uid`s. On my test machine docker has `guid` of 999, which is why it is displayed as such on the host side.

As for "fixing" this you can either use a (host-level) known `uid` in the dockerfile instead of the default one, or you can just ignore it, as it is working exactly as intended, unless there's a specific reason why you want it to display a certain name for a certain `uid` in your host system.

Answer (score 2):

Our Dockerfile has lines like

```
ARG uid=1000
ARG gid=1000
RUN groupadd -g $gid myuser && useradd -lm -u $uid -g $gid myuser
USER myuser
```

Then we build with

```
docker-compose build --build-arg uid=`id -u` --build-arg gid=`id -g` mydocker
```

So that the uid and gid of the user created inside the Docker is the same as the uid and gid of the user running docker-compose outside the Docker.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the files your docker image is built on :  https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/tree/bb7ea52db4e12d3fb526450d22382d5cd8cd41ca/5.7

In the Dockerfile you can read:

```
RUN groupadd -r mysql && useradd -r -g mysql mysql
```

which creates a user that might have the UID/GID couple your are seeing.

And in the entrypoint.sh file, there is:

```
chown -R mysql:mysql "$DATADIR"
```

which is executed every time you `run` the container.

To be sure, try:

```
docker run exec -ti <nameOfContainer|containerHash> bash -c "id mysql"
```

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest a fix;

```
version: '3.5'
services:
 mysql-server:
  image: mysql:5.7
  environment:
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root_pwd
  volumes:
   - ./var/lib/mysql:/var/lib/mysql:rw
  entrypoint: chmod -R 755 /var && tail -f /dev/null
```

Adding the entrypoint in the `docker-compose.yaml` file to make the recursive permission changes for you when you run `docker compose` (change the directory to what you need)

Comment: That will cause the database to not start: the container will only run the `chmod` command and then exit.