# What does chown 999 do?

Tags: docker, chown

I know what `chmod` (change mode) and what `chown` (change owner) do.

I also understand what the numbers mean after `chmod` do.

I was going through a [docker tutorial](https://youtu.be/-XzMfd4XQak?t=410) and I saw `chown 999` being used.

What does it mean and do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why docker-compose creates directories/files with user:group 999:999?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55241474/why-docker-compose-creates-directories-files-with-usergroup-999999)

Comment: 999 is a user in the system. If you type `id 999` you can check it. So in the tutorial he's changing the owner of the file to this user.

Comment: @Taron yes it does. Thanks.